# How to Improve Core Web Vitals Affected by AdSense Scripts?

Tags: adsense, google-pagespeed, core-web-vitals

I've been working on optimizing my website's Core Web Vitals for better user experience and SEO performance. However, I've noticed that some of the AdSense scripts and assets are negatively impacting my site's performance metrics, particularly in the areas of Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) and Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS).

Upon analyzing my site's performance using tools like Google PageSpeed Insights and Lighthouse, I found that the AdSense scripts are contributing significantly to the total blocking time and render-blocking resources, ultimately leading to poor LCP and CLS scores.

I'm wondering if there are any strategies or best practices to optimize AdSense scripts and assets to minimize their impact on Core Web Vitals. Are there specific configurations, lazy-loading techniques, or other optimizations that can be implemented to improve the loading performance of AdSense ads without sacrificing ad revenue or violating AdSense policies?

I'm only calling the Adsense script once on each page. I have also optimized the site.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give specific advice without seeing the website in question, but there's some general guidance for [loading ads effectively without impacting performance](https://web.dev/articles/loading-ads-page-speed) that might be useful to you.